# Serve 404 page based on field within a node

Tags: 7

I have a content type which has a field that when set to a specific value it should serve a 404 page instead of the nodes content.

What's the nicest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [template_preprocess_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7) for this

```
function templatename_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'myfield') {
    if ($variables['element']['#items'][0]['value'] == 'somevalue') {
      drupal_not_found();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using node--node-type.tpl.php
using dsm get field value and set value against it

```
if (your_field_name = your_condition){
print '404 page';   //or to redirect on specific node page
}else{
print render($page['content']);  
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually set a 404 header, instead it'll set 200 which isn't what I want.

Comment: can you elaborate it

Comment: A 404 page should also set the HTTP header of 404, because your only outputting the text 404 the HTTP header will be 200.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) for this. It might be overkill to install it for just this purpose but if you have it installed I think it's a nice visual way of doing it instead of a code snippet.

Install Panels and create a node view variant under admin/structure/pages/edit/node_view.

Set the type to be HTTP response code.
Check selection rules to be used.

Select which response code you which to give.

Configure the selection rules to be triggered according to your rules.